# How to implement logging in custom module in Spring XD?

Tags: spring, logging, slf4j, logback, spring-xd

It's not so easy to debug custom module deployed to the Spring XD runtime (version 1.3.1-RELEASE).

I'm aware of `log` sink, however it's something different that I want to achieve.

I'd like to add my own log messages to the XD log (ideally to the `STDOUT` alongside it's own logs). These log messages are generated in my custom module (processor in this case) using `slf4j` API.

---

I've added:

1. `org.slf4j.Logger#info` invocation to the processor class
2. `logback-classic` dependency to the `pom.xml` (w/o a version, as it's managed by `spring-xd-module-parent` `dependencyManagement`
3. `logback.xml` to the `resources` directory
4. `logback-test.xml` to the `test` `resources` directory

Log messages are logged into `STDOUT` during integration test invocation (via `SingleNodeIntegrationTestSupport`), however they don't appear in the XD log when module is uploaded or stream using it is deployed.

`logback.xml` contents (identical for `-test`):

> ```
> <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
>     <encoder>
>         <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
>         <charset>UTF-8</charset>
>     </encoder>
> </appender>
>
> <logger name="com.maxromanovsky" level="debug" />
> <logger name="org.springframework" level="warn" />
> <logger name="org.apache.zookeeper" level="error" />
>
> <root level="warn">
>     <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
> </root>
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container logback configuration files can be found in `xd/config` (`xd-container-logback.groovy` and `xd-singlenode-logback.groovy`).

You need to add your custom logger configuration there.